# Google Chrome jQuery problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, grails

I have a site (in Grails) which periodically submits forms (formRemote, ajax forms in Grails) using the setInterval method and jQuery. It's working in all browsers (even in IE), but sometimes it doesn't work in Google Chrome. Here's a fragment of the js I'm using:

```
window.setInterval(updateGroupMessages,500)
function updateGroupMessages() {
    console.log('hello from updateGroupMessages');
    $(function(){$('#updateGroupMessagesBlock').submit();});
}
```

I've checked the console in Google Chrome, but there are no error messages. I Honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is the `console.log` being triggered? If so, the JavaScript is running fine, and I would guess that something is happening to the submission between your code sending it and your server receiving it.

Comment: Yes, it's being triggered...

Comment: What happens if you remove the closure from around your `.submit()` call? If it should be anywhere, you should wrap it around the entire code block.

Comment: First I didn't even put it there, but I read somewhere that I need to wrap the code in a document ready.

Comment: All your code would normally be wrapped in `$(document).ready` -- not just certain parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order so you declare your function first then set the interval for it.

```
function updateGroupMessages() {
    console.log('hello from updateGroupMessages');
    $(function(){$('#updateGroupMessagesBlock').submit();});
}
window.setInterval(updateGroupMessages,500)
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't help :(

Comment: And you have no other intervals running?

Comment: No, I have other intervals running, but sometimes that's not a problem for chrome and always not a problem for other browsers. It's essential that I have more intervals running.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the closure from your `.submit()` line to the entire block of code:

```
$(function() {
    window.setInterval(updateGroupMessages,500);
    function updateGroupMessages() {
        console.log('hello from updateGroupMessages');
        $('#updateGroupMessagesBlock').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've noticed that when I refresh the browser, everything works fine, if this is any help.

Comment: I doubt that we can be of any more help unless you can narrow down the source of the problem. As I said before, since you say there are no JavaScript errors, the problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: But why only in Google Chrome?

Comment: I'm submitting a few formRemotes and updating a few divs with the formRemotes' help. That's all I can tell you.